# Use runit to only boot up the service and not supervise

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, init, unicorn, runit

I have a EC2 setup where I have a chef script that sets up a rails app with unicorn. Since I'm using [application_ruby](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_ruby) script, which uses [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) to launch Unicorn at boot, I run into this problem where I need to manually disable runit after boot with `sudo sv once app`. Otherwise, runit will interfere with Unicorn's zero downtime deployments and starts spawning new unicorn masters that keep erroring out, which in turn prevent future Unicorn restarts.

So I've been looking for a way to have runit only boot up the initial Unicorn instance and then not supervise it, so it wouldn't automatically spawn new Unicorn instances when the original is restarted by a deploy script. Currently, my `/etc/sv/app/run` looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/deployer/app/current

exec 2>&1
exec /usr/bin/chpst \
  -u deployer:deployer \
  bundle exec \
  unicorn \
 -E production \
 -c /etc/unicorn/app.rb
```

What I have to do now, is manually call `sudo sv once app` to prevent runit from freaking out later, but I'd like not having to do that manually. I tried adding `sv once app` to the end of my `/etc/sv/app/run`, but that had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running `sv once app` in a separate recipe that is executed after your `application_ruby` stuff?  You could even use a tempfile located in `/tmp` to ensure it only was executed once since the last boot of the box.

Comment: .. Don't use runit - just use init.d or service. The whole point of runit is to monitor the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `sv o app` directly from your run script to change it to the expected mode. Modifying what you have:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/deployer/app/current
sv o app
exec 2>&1
exec /usr/bin/chpst \
  -u deployer:deployer \
  bundle exec \
  unicorn \
 -E production \
 -c /etc/unicorn/app.rb
```